# How to start Jetty with multiple standalone instances?

Tags: linux, jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to start two instances of Jetty in different ports (one is 8080 and the other is 443).

I created two jetty.base directories using start.jar with the parameter --add-to-startd.

When I run "java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar" in the first app directory it starts normally, port 8080.

When I run "java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar" in the second app directory, it kills the first process. And after that starts normally, port 443.

If I change the order the same thing happens.

How can I run more than one instance of Jetty without one killing the other?

- Jetty: jetty-distribution-9.3.0.M2
- Java: jdk1.8.0_25
- Operating system: Linux CentOS release 6.6

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the process died because the server was out of memory.

I didn't see any Exception in the logs, but monitoring the machine, I saw that when the memory was close to 100% the process died.